# Socratic badge-how to get it?

Tags: support, badges

In the description, one gets (gold) socratic badge if one "Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record ". I Don;t understand what does it mean, especially the second part. At the time I have 49/100 part to complete this badge.

Answer (score 6):

From the relevant post on the main meta [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

> #### Socratic
>
> - gold; <strike>awarded once</strike>
> - Asked a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintained a positive question record
>
> **Additional criteria for this badge family:**
>
> - Any open question that is not deleted and has a score >= 1 is considered *well-received*
> - Only days where *all* questions asked have been well-received, count
> - A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`. Questions that have been downvoted *and* closed *and* deleted count three times in this calculation!

Comment: For additional background, see also [Jon Ericson's Meta Stack Exchange post announcing this badge group](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259).

Comment: Strange. Thanks for the info. It seems it was originally intended like this, then scrapped but now it is still like this. Not sure what to make of it. // Nobody can suggest edits on my posts here. ;D [The stress must be on "here" of course as it is a per-site meta.]